# DOM parsing in Java not able to get the nested notes

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have to  parse an xml file in which I have many name value pairs.
I have to update the value in case it matches a given name.
I opted for DOM parsing as it can easily traverse any part and can quickly update the value.
It is however giving me some wired results when I am running it on my sample file.

I am new to DOM so if someone can help it can solve my problem.
I tried various things but all resulting in either null values for content or #text node name.
I am not able to get the text content of the tag.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFilePath);

//This will get the first NVPair
Node NVPairs = document.getElementsByTagName("NVPairs").item(0);


//This should assign nodes with all the child nodes of NVPairs. This should be ideally    
//<nameValuePair>
NodeList nodes = NVPairs.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    // I think it will consider both starting and closing tag as node so checking for if it has 
    //child     
    if(node.hasChildNodes())
    {
        //This should give me the content in the name tag.
        //However this is not happening
        if ("Tom".equals(node.getFirstChild().getTextContent())) {
            node.getLastChild().setTextContent("2000000");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><application>
<NVPairs>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <value>12</value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <value>121</value>
    </nameValuePair>
</NVPairs>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#getChildNodes()` and `#getFirstChild()` returns all kinds of nodes, not just Element nodes, and in this case the first child of `<name>Tom</name>` is a Text node (with newline and blanks). So your test will never return true.

However, in cases like this, it always much more convenient to use XPath:

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(
            "//nameValuePair/value[preceding-sibling::name = 'Tom']", document,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        node.setTextContent("2000000");
    }
```

I.e., return all `<name>` elements that has a preceding sibling element `<name>` with value 'Tom'.